# Core Data freezing all the app

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, concurrency, freeze

I'm having problems with `Core Data` concurrency on my iOS app.
On my `executeFetchRequest` I tried to synchronize the `managedObjectContext` request, but some times this method makes my app freeze.

```
- (NSArray *)synchronizedWithFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request andError:(NSError **)error
{
    @synchronized(self.managedObjectContext)
    {
        return [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:error];
    }
}
```

I've already tried many things like `lock`/`unlock`, `performBlock`/`performBlockAndWait`, `dispatch_sync`/`dispatch_async` and nothing seems to work.

Managed Object Context creation:

```
 ...
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

Is there some way around this? and keep my request returning the results objects on this method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronising on the MOC suggests that there is more than one thread accessing the same MOC.
That in itself is a violation of CoreData concurrency protocols.

This access is prohibited unless it is wrapped in the context `performBlock:` method (or its "wait" counterpart). this will negate the need for the `@synchronized` block altogether.

This thread/queue "boundness" extends to the contexts fetched/registered managed objects, and so, you will not be able to access them as the return values of your method.

Comment: Thanks Dan! So what is the best solution to handle with multithreads accessing Core Data? One MOC for each thread?

Comment: start by reading [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html). and you could probably use [THIS](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/)

Comment: In general: you have a context bound per-thread/queue, passing objects between contexts is done by passing their `objectID`s and fetching them in the other context

Comment: I'm trying to implement the Nested Contexts pattern but i didn't understood how to use the temporary contexts. Should I user a temporary context to each fetch? When I should use the main context?

Comment: You use a temporary context or each background operation, or as a background operation since the context choose its on queue to execute on (use `performBlock:`). each context should fetch the objects it want to interact with by request or ID. the main context is used as a focal point for private contexts to merge changes to and report them to UI. don't forget to save all the way to the store to persist your changes.